# Chrome throttles things like requestAnimationFrame in my iframe

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, iframe

We provide an embeddable configurator which can be added by clients via iframe. They interact with the iframe with a JavaScript API.

In some integrations, it seems that Chrome throttles the iframe in some cases. Often this happens (but not exclusively) when the client preloads the configurator in a hidden "div".

By throttling, I mean that Chrome slows down everything. Network requests, requestAnimationFrame, requestIdleCallback etc. Slow down can be some 100ms but sometimes it's also 10 seconds.

When the user clicks on the iframe throttling is ended and everything works as fast as expected.

We tried to indicate Chrome that the iframe should not be throttled with the help of JavaScript.

We tried things like `iframe.contentWindow.focus()` or `iframe.contentWindow.click()` but this is not very reliable. This works on some integrations and on others not.

Is there some possibility to tell Chrome that some iframe is a trusted iframe which shouldn't be throttled? Ideally some JavaScript. A browser setting wouldn't work in our case since the users of the configurator are end consumers who browse on a website/webshop.

Comment: How hidden is the div? Can you set up an MCVE?

Comment: @Kaiido how hidden, this is different on every webshop. If we would know which CSS or combination makes the problem we could advise our customers. I'll try to create a MCVE but I have to check which content etc I can use since some of our stuff is behind a nda.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need:

The visible state of a browser  has nothing to do with its actual visibility (which is handled through CSS). The visible state is used to define the level of resources required by the browser . If the visible state is set to true, it means that the browser  should have high priority over the resources needed to render and handle its content. On the contrary, if its visible state is set to false, it has low priority over the resources it needs.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Gecko/Chrome/API/Browser_API/setVisible